# Creating a new column in pandas using for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I want to create a new column in my data-frame using combinations of multiple values from another column.

I have tried the following code and it doesn't seem to work. the operator is not working that I can see.

```
enter code here

lst = [df1]
for column in lst:
     column.loc[(column["booking_text"] in ['SEPA-Gutschrift','SEPA-Cash 
      Management Gutsch','FASTER PAYMENTS','SCHECK-EV','BACS CREDIT','POS 
      Gutschrift','Scheckeinreichung e.V.'])
      & (column["debit_credit"] == 'Credit'), "financial_category"] = 'Reveunue_Credit'

      df1['financial_category'] = df1['financial_category']
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [df1]
for column in lst:
 column.loc[(column["booking_text"].isin(['SEPA-Gutschrift','SEPA-Cash Management 
 Gutsch','FASTER PAYMENTS', 'SCHECK-EV','BACS CREDIT','POS 
 Gutschrift','Scheckeinreichung e.V.'])) & (column["debit_credit"] == 'Credit'), 'financial_category'] = 'Reveunue_Credit'
```